# Caching stylesheets with $_GET data attached

Tags: php, css, caching

I'm in the process of optimizing CMS website's CSS usage and I decided it would be a good idea to serve the CSS through PHP so I could send the ID of the current page to the stylesheet, e.g:

```
<link href="/css/style.php?id=<?php echo $page_id; ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I did this because I thought it would be a good way to stop CSS meant for different pages being loaded on pages that didn't need it. Then today it struck me, this setup means when a new user clicks an internal link, they won't be able to use their cached stylesheet and will have to download a new stylesheet for every page.

Obviously this isn't the way forward, does anybody know a better way of doing it? I've considered using session data, but I'd rather not because if anybody had cookies off it would break. I've also considered using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in the stylesheet but I'm worried about false positives.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does the page ID trigger in the style sheet? Because if you're just doing selective loading, you may be best off dropping that altogether and having one big fat style sheet that gets loaded once, and gets cached from then on.

Comment: It triggers things like the contact form CSS being loaded only on the contact us page etc. I used to have it all as one big stylesheet, but Page Speed told me off :(

Comment: why exactly did it tell you off? Size? Loading time? How large is the style sheet?

Comment: One of the suggestions was "Remove unused CSS" with a red circle next to it. The stylesheet of this particular site is 12KB but this is more of a general question than about one site

Comment: I see. Starting to split a 12kb style sheet makes no sense IMO, I'm with @gnur there - it's better to have the whole thing requested only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that caching is always better then serving up dynamic spreadsheets.

The bottleneck in pretty much every webapp is bandwith/latency. So not having to request a file is better then serving a lot of perhaps smaller files that may require a bit less processing power.